# Projectile bouncing of game boundaries not working properly

Tags: c#, xna

In my game there is a powerup that makes the players projectiles bounce off the walls of the play area. I can't seem to get it to work, game boundaries are horizontal and vertical as normal.

Currently my code is this;

```
public void UpdatePlasma()
{
    Direction = new Vector2((float)Math.Cos(Angle), (float)Math.Sin(Angle));
    //Vector2 Velocity = new Vector2(1, 1);
    Position += Direction * projSpeed;

    if ((Position.X >= viewport.Width) || (Position.X <= 0))
    {
        Angle = -Angle;
    }

    else if ((Position.Y >= viewport.Height) || (Position.Y <= 0))
    {
        Angle = -Angle;
    }
}
```

This sort of works. The projectiles will bounce of the top and bottom boundaries sometimes (think this might be due to angle becoming 0 therefore direction not changed when negated and goes through) and not at all on the left and right boundaries. I then tried multiplying my Position by the commented out Velocity vector and then negating either the X or Y coordinate but this didn't work at all the projectile just continued on out of the boundaries.

Comment: The projectiles angle will not be -angle after the bounce. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830791/find-radians-reflection-angle for how to calculate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Radians counter-clockwise (positive)] [image: Radians clockwise (negative)]

These diagrams illustrate the radian angle as you move clockwise or counter-clockwise around a circle. I'm assuming that, in your game, that the direction of the red arrows is equivalent to the movement of your ball given a particular angle (that is, 0 rad is right, PI/2 rad is up, and so on).

Using these diagrams as a reference, consider the four cases of the ball hitting the walls: top, right, bottom, and left when moving up, right, down, and left respectively.

First I will go over the cases using the current code to illustrate why the incorrect behaviour is happening. I'll be referring to the "incidence angle" as the angle the ball has before the collision (with the respective wall), and the "deflected angle" as the angle the ball should have after the collision.

---

Using `deflected_angle = -incidence_angle`

**Case 1:** ball moving up, hits the top wall:

```
incidence_angle = PI/2 = up
deflected_angle = -PI/2 = 3PI/2 = down
```

good!

**Case 2:** ball moving down, hits the bottom wall:

```
incidence_angle = 3PI/2 = down
deflected_angle = -3PI/2 = up
```

good!

**Case 3:** ball moving right, hits the right wall:

```
incidence_angle = 0 = right
deflected_angle = -0 = 0 = right
```

oops!

**Case 4:** ball moving left, hits the left wall:

```
incidence_angle = PI = left
deflected_angle = -PI = PI = left
```

oops!

---

So now that we have an understanding of why the current code is behaving correctly in some cases and not in others, we have to come up with some solution. It should be clear that we are not interested in simply negating the angle. Rather, (at least for the four sample cases), we want the ball to deflect in the opposite direction; we can do this by adding PI to our angle, which is a half-circle turn.

Now let's go over our cases with the new equation.

---

Using `deflected_angle = incidence_angle + PI`

**Case 1:** ball moving up, hits the top wall:

```
incidence_angle = PI/2 = up
deflected_angle = PI/2 + PI = 3PI/2 = down
```

good!

**Case 2:** ball moving down, hits the bottom wall:

```
incidence_angle = 3PI/2 = down
deflected_angle = 3PI/2 + PI = 5PI/2 = PI/2 = up
```

good!
(Note that `5PI/2` makes a complete lap around the circle, and then some. We can get the same angle by computing `5PI/2 - 2PI`, which is `PI/2`.)

**Case 3:** ball moving right, hits the right wall:

```
incidence_angle = 0 = right
deflected_angle = 0 + PI = PI = left
```

good!

**Case 4:** ball moving left, hits the left wall:

```
incidence_angle = PI = left
deflected_angle = PI + PI = 2PI = 0 = right
```

good!

---

I recommend trying this solution and observing the result. You should still observe odd behaviour when the ball hits the sides at an angle other than the four we're considering (particularly, it will bounce back towards the direction it came, rather than deflecting as we'd expect physically).

To correct this, when we hit a vertical wall (the left or right), we want to calculate our deflection angle as `deflected_angle = PI - incident_angle`, and when we hit a horizontal wall (top or bottom) we want to calculate the angle as `deflected_angle = 2PI - incident_angle`.

Why this is the case is illustrated in the following diagram. For brevity, we'll only look at the case of the ball hitting the top wall; the other cases are illustrated similarly.

Red vectors indicate the incidence angle, and blue vectors indicate the deflected angle. Each vector appears twice, only having been translated, which doesn't change their meaning (the only purpose is to clarify the diagram). Also, the angles have been additionally illustrated as the arcs `A`, `B`, and `C` (ie: the red vector and `A`, and the blue vector and `C` are representing the same thing).

[image: Deflection example (vertical normal)]

From this diagram, we can derive `C = PI + B` and `B = PI - A`. We put these together to arrive at the final equation. (note that `C` is our deflected angle and `A` is the incidence angle).

```
let:
C = PI + B
B = PI - A

then:
C = PI + (PI - A)
C = PI + PI - A
C = 2PI - A

note:
2PI = 0
therefore, C = -A
(this is why the top and bottom cases worked)

therefore:
deflected_angle = 2PI - incidence_angle
```

Again, you can check the other cases in a similar way and arrive at the rest of the equations. You'll notice that the ball hitting the bottom is solved with the same equation as hitting the top, and you'll find the equation `deflected_angle = PI - incident_angle` is the same for the left and right.

If you want to read further, you can deflect your ball off of any line (ie: not just horizontal or vertical); this can be done by observing a normal to the surface you are deflecting off of. I'll refrain from listing and particular links because they can become broken; instead, I'll recommend some Googling (they'll probably be around for a while ;) ).

---

## Additional Considerations

Another issue you'll have to deal with in game physics, at least with using discrete physics (as opposed to continuous approaches, which attempt to determine collision times before they occur), is that objects will be penetrating each other. To understand the problem with this, consider what would happen if your ball stayed outside of the boundaries for more than one update cycle (which may or may not be a possibility depending on your update frequency, ball velocity, ball acceleration, and collision resolution). On the first update cycle, say you detected the ball is above the boundary, so you correctly calculate the deflected angle and set that as the new angle for the ball. Now, on your second update cycle, you move the ball according to this angle, but the ball is still above the boundary (that is, it did not move far enough given its velocity and acceleration to re-enter the boundary); your code will again detect the ball is above the bounds and deflect the ball upwards! The result is your ball will either get stuck in the wall for a short time, get stuck in the wall permanently, or leave the playing field entirely. There are numerous ways to counteract this problem that are outside the scope of this particular question topic.

There is also one missing case (well, actually four, but its the same idea for all): what if the ball crosses a corner of the field? If you only treat the ball as having hit a single wall, your deflection angle will be incorrect and will cause the ball to fly out of the boundaries. Therefore, you'll need additional logic to account for this possibility.

Comment: Even better explanation now! Really helped with my understanding thanks very much. I have a much better understanding of things now too.